# How to add hyperlink in jasper report using jasper studio 6.03

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jasper studio . I want to create a report that have a field value link with other table or report . i read some tutorial they they show right click on the text field and select hyperlink . but in my case there is no hyperlink when i right click on text .

please any one who is familiar with jasper studio 6.0 can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have installed Jaspersoft Studio 6.0.3 and hyperlink option over text field seems to be quite hidden against as it was in ireport in standart perspective.

You can find **Hyperlink option between properties tabs** when you click on some text field in table. It is fifth tab after Inheritence and before last Advanced. It might be out of monitor, if you have not so big width of left panel :(

hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

Now i am using **ireport** instead of **jaspersoft studio** 
that is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the location of the hyperlink property in Jaspersoft Studio 6.20.0, and how to use it:

[image]